# Convolution of two continuous functions is differentiable?

Tags: integration, continuity, convolution

Let $f, g$ be continuous and **not** differentiable functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.
Let $h=f \ast g$ be the convolution of $f$ and $g$, i.e. $h(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x).g
(x-t) dx$. Is $h$ differentiable? If not, under what condition $h$ is differentiable?

My motivation example is that: $f(x)= \max ( \frac{-1}{2w} |x|+1, 0 )$ and $h=f\ast f$. From numerical computation, I observe that $h$ is differentiable. But I don't know how to prove this. It is well-known that if one of $f$ or $g$ is differentiable then $h$ is, but I couldn't find any result with respect to non-differentiability $f$ and$g$.

[image]

Comment: There are continuous functions whose convolution are nowhere differentiable [This](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X13010871) maybe of interest to you. If cone of the terms in $f*g$ is continously differentiable and along with its derivative bounded, then $f*g$ is differentiable.

Comment: @OliverDiaz your reference is really valuable, I will check it now!

Comment: @OliverDiaz Could you please tell me where I could find the precise definition of "cone"  in your comment? when I google I just find "Collapsed cone convolution", is it?

Comment: is was a typo, it should have been "if one of ..."